# Ubuntu machine behind a LAN as openvpn server

Tags: server, openvpn

I am running an ubuntu server with LAN ip on which I want to run openvpn server which will provide access to the LAN that ubuntu server is in. I will be opening a port on my router through which the ubuntu server will listen on. The network will be 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 The (eth0) ip of ubuntu server will be 192.168.9.10. The LAN gateway and dns server will be 192.168.0.1 (router). I have partially worked on it by [using this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openvpn.html#openvpn-configuration). But the openvpn server fails to start, so something isn't right in my conf file. So what settings should I have in my openvpn conf file?

Comment: Have you took a look in your system log for error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help you debug your problem, you should do the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop
# Or 'sudo stop openvpn' if you are on a very new Ubuntu system
sudo openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

You should now get the openvpn output right on your terminal.

Comment: It seams the guide that I linked is somewhat outdated, I somehow got it working by following the official openvpn guide.

Comment: Ok, could you please close the question?

Comment: What was the problem/solution?

Comment: Can anyone link to the _Official OpenVPN Guide_?